# How to set margin in section?

Tags: html, css

Cant understand how to set margin in wrapped element. For example i have

```
<body>
    <section id="main">
        <div id="video">

        </div>

    </section>
</body>


section#main{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 7% auto 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.86;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}

div#video{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[image]

As you can see - margin only on left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Margin will collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) under some circumstances. Why not use padding?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is an example of [**collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). Add `overflow:auto;` to `section#main`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YUF4d/)**

Answer (score 0):

Well :**margin: 7% auto 0**  will render has **margin:0 auto** since your outter container does not have an height.